# Prove that E(E(Y|X)*X)=E(Y*X)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

How can one prove that:

$$ E( E(Y \mid X) \cdot X)=E(Y \cdot X)$$ if $E(Y \mid X)$ is well-defined.

Are we free to use the law of iterated expectations? I am confused since now the expectation of the product is not the product of expectations and I am not sure if we can bluntly apply lie and just replace the conditional expectation with the random variable itself.

Comment: $E(X*E(Y|X)) = E(E(XY|X)) = E(XY)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key ingredient to the proof is that $\mathbb E[X Y \mid X] = \mathbb E [Y \mid X] \cdot X$; once you have established this, then you can immediately use the law of iterated expectations. (How you prove *that* lemma will depend on whether you're doing measure-theoretic probability or not, but it's not too bad in either case.)

Comment: My measure theoretic knowledge is very basic, in particular in measure theoretic probability, especially conditional expectations. Do you have any reference I could look at?

Comment: If you're not already delving deeply into measure theory (specifically as it relates to conditional expectations), it is honestly probably a lot more machinery than it's worth (at least for this problem). Rather, take whatever definition of $\mathbb E[Z \mid X]$ you've got, set $Z = X \cdot Y$, and the result should follow fairly naturally. (It may make the proof easier to assume that $X, Y$ are discrete.)